# Recursive method calling

Tags: c#, recursion

I need to call a method and till the time the return response is 1 , I need to run that method again and again.

My code looks like:

```
public class TrackdoId
{
    public static string PsExecTrack(string query, string execFile)
    {
        string result = null;
        string PSData = "";
        var proc = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = execFile,
                Arguments = query,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        };

        proc.Start();
        log.Debug("PSExec Process started for checking log file");
        while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
        {
            PSData += proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        };

        string doid = PSData.Substring(PSData.IndexOf("{"));
        dynamic data = JObject.Parse(doid);

        string count = data.reportedCount;
        int asset = Int32.Parse(count);

        while (asset != 1)
        {
            TrackdoId.PsExecTrack(query, execFile)
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

But this results in an infinite loop.

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: What changes on each recursion?  Each query should return a set of values and then instead of the for loop "while (asset!= 1)" you would enumerate through the results of the query."dynamic data".

Comment: @jdweng The asset value should be changing from 0 to 1 .and till the time its not 1 I need to run this function

Comment: @user13199266 It doesn't change because you are looking at the value on the current stack while the recursive call with update a new value on a different stack.  You either need to save to a static shared variable, or preferably return the value to determine if you need to continue or not.

Comment: What you are saying doesn't make any sense.  Look at your code.  You keep on parsing the same query over and over and over again so you are in an endless loop.

Comment: @jdweng I know thats what I am trying to understand. How should I be achieving the purpose because this way it always ends up in an infinite loop.

Comment: Read my previous responses.  You cannot keep on sending the same parameters in every recursive call : PsExecTrack(string query, string execFile).  If query and execFile are always the same you will be in an endless loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive functions need three things to succeed:

1. An exit condition,
2. Work to do, including something that affects the exit condition
3. A recursive call.

I suggest the exit condition be the *first* thing in your recursive method.

The `while` loop you have in there doesn't really make sense; if you're going to loop with a `while`, you probably don't really need the recursive call.

Bottom line?  You need an exit condition that works.

---

Here is an example of a recursive function that works:

```
int factorial(int n) 
{
   if(n == 1) return 1;
   return n * factorial(n - 1);
}
```

and this is how it works:

[image]